# What will happen to the session after redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I would ask a general question:

What will happen with the Session, Log-in cookie in the case situation:

The case is Redirect from a web application to another then the second application to the first one?

```
A => B => A
```

Will the be persist or a new one will be created? or something other?

Answer (score 0):

It will persist, so long as the session hasn't timed out (default 30 minutes)

The cookie will stay in the browser, but is application specific. So in your example, if application A deposited a session cookie on the clients browser, application B would not be able to access it. If application B then redirects back to A before the session times out, you will still be able to access it in application A.

-Mikey

Answer (score 0):

It would be persisted until the session times-out.

Answer (score 0):

If the transition from `B => A` happens in the timeframe where the Cookie Data and the Session are valid you still will be logged in.

Beware **Session Lifetime != Cookie life time**

If a site proves additional information you may be logged out though. E.g. Refererer or something like this.